# Expanding empty hash in variable with double splat in Ruby

Tags: ruby, splat, double-splat

I got this strange behavior trying to expand the hash variable using double splat. Do not know why this is happening.

**My ruby version**

`ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800)`

**Scenario**

```
class MyClass
  def my_method; end
end

MyClass.new.my_method(*[]) # returns nil

MyClass.new.my_method(**{}) # returns nil

MyClass.new.my_method(*[], **{}) # returns nil


# Using variables

values = []
k_values = {}

MyClass.new.my_method(*values) # returns nil

MyClass.new.my_method(**k_values) # *** ArgumentError Exception: Wrong number of arguments. Expected 0, got 1.

MyClass.new.my_method(*values, **k_values) # *** ArgumentError Exception: Wrong number of arguments. Expected 0, got 1.


# In summary

MyClass.new.my_method(**{}) # returns nil

MyClass.new.my_method(**k_values) # *** ArgumentError Exception: Wrong number of arguments. Expected 0, got 1.
```

Does any one knows why this is happening? Is this a bug?

Comment: `my_method` code?

Comment: Ops, I forgot it! Updating now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it very looks like a bug

```
def foo(*args)
  args
end

foo(**{})
# => []

h = {}

foo(**h)
# => [{}]
```

It passes empty hash as first argument in case of double splat of variable.

My version is `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]`

Comment: I updated my question. I forgot to put the implementation of the method. Could you try again but without receiving any parameters in `foo`?

Comment: I understand you had no parameters in your method. In my answer I shown why you received `ArgumentError Exception` - because double splat on variable passes empty hash as first argument into the method. @rafaels88

Comment: Yes, you are right... I made some tests right now following you line of thinking, and if you pass `foo(**{a: 1})` and then `h = {a: 1}; foo(**h)`, the behavior is different than passing empty hash as you passed in your example. It seems like a bug. Thank you very much for the diagnosis!